# Error in Android Studio Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'

Tags: android, android-studio

I got Error in Android Studio

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>
> Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation' and 'testApi'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>
> Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

How to fix this a cant run app!!

Comment: this is not an error, it's only a warning. You can resolve it by changing all of your dependency which using `compile` to implementation`.